# Problema en la toma de scanf y el almacenamiento de texto en C++

Tags: c++, c, string

Este es el código de mi programa:

```
 #include stdio.h
 #include stdlib.h
 #include string.h

 int main () 
 {
        string a;
        string help = "-h";
        printf("Por favor introduzca la orden. Si desea ver la ayuda introduzca -h");
        scanf(&a);
        if ( a == help) 
        {
            printf("\n\nComandos y expresiones de iptables:"); 
        }
        else 
        {
            system("iptables %c && iptables -L -v -n", a); 
        }
        return 0; 
}
```

El tema es que no consigo que funcione ni el if ni las variables string ya que gcc me dice esto:

```
TerFirewall.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

TerFirewall.cpp:5:2: error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope
  string a;

TerFirewall.cpp:6:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘help’
  string help = "-h";


TerFirewall.cpp:8:9: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
  scanf(&a);


TerFirewall.cpp:9:12: error: ‘help’ was not declared in this scope
  if ( a == help) {
```

He probado varias veces cambiando nimiedades como en vez de usar string para la declaración de las variables, usar char pero dice lo mismo del error "string". También intenté probando otra forma para almacenar el texto en la variable `string` pero si dejo comillas simples sigue el mismo error y si se las saco dice que la variable h no ha sido declarada.

Y con el `if` es algo parecido porque no reconoce el `help`. Y con `scanf()` no sé como hacer ya que he visto en otros foros que es mejor que `getchar()`, pero no sé.

Answer (score 1):

Joaquin, tienes un buen lío de conceptos.

#### 1. Inclusiones mal hechas.

Las inclusiones requieren comillas o paréntesis angulares:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
```

o

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

La diferencia entre usar las comillas o los paréntesis angulares consiste en dónde se inicia la búsqueda del archivo de cabecera. Usando comillas la cabecera se empezará a buscar en la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo de código (extensión `c` o `cpp`), usando los paréntesis angulares se empezará a buscar en la carpeta en que se encuentren las librerías del lenguaje.

Olvidar las comillas o los paréntesis angulares provocará fallos.

#### 2. `C` no dispone de objetos `string`.

La cabecera `string.h` es una librería de [c](/questions/tagged/c) que [proporciona una serie de funciones](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) para trabajar sobre arreglos de carácteres cuyo final está marcado con el caracter nulo (`\0`), pero no dispone de objeto `string`.

El objeto [`string`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) pertenece a la librería [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), y se trata de una plantilla que gestiona cadenas de caracteres que no necesariamente deben finalizar con caracter nulo, ya que almacena internamente el tamaño.

#### ¿Qué está pasando?

Sospecho que pese a que has pegado las inclusiones mal, estas son correctas en tu equipo y al copiar-pegar tu código aquí se ha *des-formateado*.

Si el problema no es el formato de las inclusiones ¿cuál es el problema? Pues lo mencionado en el punto 2: Has incluido la cabecera [c](/questions/tagged/c) y usado un objeto `string` que no existe (pues no pertenece a dicha librería), de ahí que te surja el error:

> ```
> error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope
> ```

Ya que no has incluido la librería adecuada, que sería:

```
#include <string>
```

La cúal es una cabecera de C++, no de C. Las cabeceras de C++ no tienen extensión de archivo: `<iostream>`, `<vector>`, `<string>`, etc... excepto las cabeceras que existen por compatibilidad con C: `<math.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, etc...

La mayoría de cabeceras de `C` disponen de una versión *portada* a `C++` a la que se le ha quitado la extensión, se les ha añadido el prefijo "c" (por ejemplo `<cmath>`, `<cstdint>`, `<cstring>`) y han sido adaptadas a `C++`. Si estás trabajando con `C++` deberías usar estas últimas no las de `C`.

#### Conclusión.

Tienes un lío entre los lenguajes que quieres usar, decide si quieres programar en C++ o en C y una vez sabido, usa las librerías convenientes para ello.

Answer (score 0):

Acá pongo las errores y sus correcciones.

```
Error  ----------> Corrección
scanf(&a);          scanf("%c", a);
string a;           char a[800];
string help ="-h";  char help[5] = "help";
```

El scanf(&a) esta mal en su sintaxis, ya que entre comillas dobles se especifica el tipo de variable que se va a almacenar seguido de la variable a la que se almacena (en este caso a).
Con string pasa algo parecido, ya que la declaración esta erronea, ya que un string es parte de la variable char, por lo que se la especifica y entre [] el largo de la misma.Lo mismo pasa con el de help.

Comment: Joaquin, agrega una descripción de tu repuesta, es importante!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** En C, actualmente, al comienzo del programa principal, se dispone : `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ...`, por defecto. Si en el compilador que utilices aparece por defecto de otro modo, déjalo como aparezca.

**2.** No existe el tipo string como tal, sino arrays de caracteres con terminos de cadenas '\0'.

**3.** scanf no admite espacios por defecto, y no está realmente depurado. En C también está disponible gets(), que está bastante mejor.

**4.** No puedes comparar directamente dos cadenas, porque no son dos variables sino dos arrays de caracteres, son matrices. Entonces usaremos la función strcmp() para ello.

**5.** La sintaxis de system(), no es como la de printf, entonces, para procesar la instrucción en el formato del comando, usaremos sprintf().

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
        char a[512]="";
        char comm_[570]="";
        printf("Por favor introduzca la orden. Si desea ver la ayuda introduzca -h :\n\n");
        gets(a);
        //  scanf("%s",a);   // scanf() no admite espacios por defecto, por ello puse gets(), que además está más depurado.
        printf("\n");
        if (0 == strcmp(a,"-h")) 
            printf("\n\nComandos y expresiones de iptables:"); 
        else 
        {
            sprintf(comm_,"iptables %s && iptables -L -v -n",a);
            system(comm_); 
        }
return 1;
```

*Nota : He probado y comprobado que funciona el código que sugiero en Dev C. En caso de que en tu compilador no dispones de gets(), usa scanf() tal como está en el comentario.*

Answer (score 0):

Si estas programando en C++ ¿Porque mejor no usas la cabecera `<iostream>`? eso resolveria muchos problemas y hasta haria mas legible tu codigo